# Full window sections and navigation

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

### Test Case

**>> [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/z68x5/) <<**

### The problem

I've been playing around with 100% width and height sections and navigating between them. It all works quite smooth - I thought. But, when a user clicks 'Base' he is redirected to the first section. That's good, but the problem arises when a user then reaches the green slide (the **fourth** one). When on this section a user clicks the next arrow (to the left) the animation is not correct anymore (whereas on the first run it is correct!)

### What should happen (and what happens on first run):

- *Green* (fourth section) slides to the right (`right: -$(window).width()`)
- *White* (fifth section) slides to the right as well (`right : 0`)

### What happens after a user has already returned to base before

- *Green* stays put (does not move at all)
- *White* slides to the right (`right : 0`) as it should

I have no idea why *Green* does nothing at all! Maybe you guys can spot the problem?

Also, if you have any tips for my code (things that can be much more logical) please put them in the comments!

Comment: This seems to work okay in Firefox 14.  What browser are you testing in?

Comment: @SableFoste I first tested in Chrome and now I've tested IE and FF as well and it doesn't work either. White overlaps the Green rather than that it pushes it aside as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first run, `#green`'s `left` and `right`'s css value is not set (aka `auto`)

After returning to 'base,' you'll see that `#green` now has `right:0` and `left:0`

Comment: You are right. I completely overlooked the errors I made there. Thanks!